# How to update api versions list in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to use "autoscaling/v2beta2" apiVersion in my configuration following [this tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics). And also I am on Google Kubernetes Engine.

However I get this error:

`error: unable to recognize "backend-hpa.yaml": no matches for kind "HorizontalPodAutoscaler" in version "autoscaling/v2beta2"`

When I list the available api-versions:

```
$ kubectl api-versions

admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apps/v1
apps/v1beta1
apps/v1beta2
authentication.k8s.io/v1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
batch/v1
batch/v1beta1
certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
cloud.google.com/v1beta1
coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1
custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
extensions/v1beta1
external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
internal.autoscaling.k8s.io/v1alpha1
metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
networking.gke.io/v1beta1
networking.k8s.io/v1
policy/v1beta1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
scalingpolicy.kope.io/v1alpha1
scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
storage.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1
```

So indeed I am missing autoscaling/v2beta2.

Then I check my kubernetes version:

```
$ kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.6", GitCommit:"abdda3f9fefa29172298a2e42f5102e777a8ec25", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-05-08T13:53:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.6-gke.13", GitCommit:"fcbc1d20b6bca1936c0317743055ac75aef608ce", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T20:50:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

So it looks like I have a version of 1.13.6. Supposedly autoscaling/v2beta2 is available since 1.12.

So why it is not available for me?

Comment: use autoscaling/v1 or autoscaling/v2beta1

Comment: report it here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73738

Comment: No I want to use the newest one because firstly the syntax is changed a lot so it is hard to find documentation. And secondly there are new features added and I want to use them.

Comment: It looks like a bug with GKE, I'd open a ticket with them. For me, it works fine in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunaltely HPA autoscaling API v2beta2 is not available on GKE yet. It can be freely used with Kubeadm and Minikube.

There is already opened issue on issuetracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/135624588